# How do you serve simple documentation for go programs using godoc as a webpage?

Tags: go, godoc

I was trying to serve a specific local go file as a documentation web page, but was not able to do it.

The [official godoc documentation](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/godoc) says:

> With the -http flag (i.e. the godoc command), it runs as a web server and presents the documentation as a web page.

```
user_me$ godoc -http=:6060
```

This does create something similar as the go page but it does not render the specific file that I want to render. So I tried to provide the name of the file I wanted:

```
user_me$ godoc -http=:6000 hello.go
```

However, it just replies with:

```
usage: godoc package [name ...]
    godoc -http=:6060
  -ex=false: show examples in command line mode
  -goroot="/usr/local/go": Go root directory
  -html=false: print HTML in command-line mode
  -http="": HTTP service address (e.g., ':6060')
  -httptest.serve="": if non-empty, httptest.NewServer serves on this address and blocks
  -index=false: enable search index
  -index_files="": glob pattern specifying index files;if not empty, the index is read from these files in sorted order
  -index_throttle=0.75: index throttle value; 0.0 = no time allocated, 1.0 = full throttle
  -links=true: link identifiers to their declarations
  -maxresults=10000: maximum number of full text search results shown
  -notes="BUG": regular expression matching note markers to show
  -play=false: enable playground in web interface
  -q=false: arguments are considered search queries
  -server="": webserver address for command line searches
  -src=false: print (exported) source in command-line mode
  -tabwidth=4: tab width
  -templates="": directory containing alternate template files
  -timestamps=false: show timestamps with directory listings
  -url="": print HTML for named URL
  -v=false: verbose mode
  -write_index=false: write index to a file; the file name must be specified with -index_files
  -zip="": zip file providing the file system to serve; disabled if empty
```

I also tried:

```
user_me$ godoc -url="localhost:8080" hello.go
```

but it didn't work.

I also tried:

```
godoc -server=localhost:8080 hello.go
```

but it replied with:

```
2014/07/01 10:45:56 open /usr/local/go/src/pkg/hello.go: no such file or directory
```

I even tried just generating the html thing itself:

```
godoc -html hello.go > hello.html
```

same error as above.

I also tried (since it was complaining that there was no file in the pkg dir):

```
godoc -html -goroo=$GOPATH hello.go > hello.html
```

At the end, I gave up. I don't know how this godoc thing works. I installed the hello.go program so that I there was something in the pkg file in the workspace. How do you generate a webpage with your documentation for your code?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

godoc operates on package and type names, not filenames.

For example, to learn about `io/ioutil` package:

- text output: `godoc io/ioutil`
- just the `ReadAll` function: `godoc io/ioutil ReadAll`
- in HTML: `godoc -html io/ioutil ReadAll`
- in the browser:

  - `godoc -http=:6060`
  - click Packages and navigate from there
  - or go directly to `http://localhost:6060/pkg/io/ioutil#ReadAll`

To view documentation for your own code, it has to be included in your `GOPATH`.

Suppose your `GOPATH` includes `$HOME/go/src`, and the file you are interested in is `$HOME/go/src/hey/world/doc.go`, you would run:

```
godoc hey/world
```

...or start godoc in HTTP mode and browse to `http://localhost:6060/pkg/hey/world`

Comment: when I did godoc `hey/world` I only got `COMMAND DOCUMENTATION` and thats it, nothing else. When you say start godoc and I go to that page I do see the name of the repo, however, it doesn't show the documentation for my only hello.go program. Why is that?

Comment: do I have to do go install again or something? That didn't really work either though...

Comment: Forgot to mention: godoc works differently if the target is an executable (i.e. `package main`); in that case it only shows the package-level comment.  For an example, see http://golang.org/src/cmd/gofmt/doc.go

Comment: also, how do u make sure that it has an overview?

Comment: Just a note, running `godoc -http=:6060` gives you the entire documentation including the standard libraries **and your own packages**. And most of the buttons displayed in the browser are **not** relevant to your code (such as "Documents", "The Project", "Help", etc)

Answer (score 9):

By default, [godoc](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc) looks at the packages it finds via $GOROOT and $GOPATH. So given that your package is in Go workspace i.e in GOPATH, you can run

`godoc fmt`

which prints out documentation for fmt package.

If you want to generate docs for your package `foo` which is in `$GOPATH/src/github.com/abcd/foo` location, you should run

`godoc github.com/abcd/foo`

With the `-http` flag, godoc runs as a web server and presents the documentation as a web page.

`godoc -http=:6060`

Now navigate to `http://localhost:6060/pkg/github.com/abcd/foo` in browser to find docs as web page.

The `-play` flag can be used to enable playground in web interface.

Comment: Don't know why this got downvoted. Everything in here is working just as described above. Upped it.

Comment: @C4d This is probably downvoted because `godoc` is the webserver cli which serves documentation while `go doc` (go binary) prints documentation to console.


The instructions above are applicable to `go doc` (console output), not `godoc` (webpage) - which is what OP is asking about.

Answer (score 2):

To show HTML doc generated for your own code

Step 1) At command line start up the document web server, that is:

`C:\>godoc -http=:6060`

Step 2) Open a browser and use an explicit url the folder your code is.

The URL structure comes from the folder names under your GOPATH.

For example:

If my GOPATH is `c:\go` and I have code in `c:\go\src\myfolder\mysubfolder`

The URL I would uses is `http://localhost:6060/pkg/myfolder/mysubfolder` and this would show an HTML page for the .go files in there

Also you can use URL `http://localhost:6060/pkg/myfolder`, which will have a link to `mysubfolder`

Notes:

- I'm not sure how to see your local code at the the `http://localhost:6060/pkg` level, maybe you can't
- It is possible to "specify additional paths" so I don't think it has to be the `src` folder, see https://blog.golang.org/godoc-documenting-go-code

Answer (score 1):

Running `godoc` on its own worked for me, but was really slow because it
generates docs for every single package in the standard library, while I only
care about the local package that I am working on. To that end, if your package is in a folder called `something`, you can move
the folder so that it looks like this:

```
godoc/src/something
```

Then, go to the `godoc` folder, and run

```
godoc -goroot .
```

Then, browse to `localhost:6060`.

Answer (score 0):

On linux, and assuming you have cd'd into the package of which you want to read the documentation.

if you are using go modules, you can run below command

```
godoc -http=:6060 & xdg-open http://localhost:6060/pkg/$(go list -m)
```

It uses the `-m` flag to get the package path even though the root module directory does not contain any `.go` file.

If you are not yet using modules, you can run,

```
godoc -http=:6060 & xdg-open http://localhost:6060/pkg/$(go list -f "{{.ImportPath}}")
```

Note that unlike `-m` this command will not work appropriately if there is no `.go` files into the directory.

Check the `go list` subcommand help at https://golang.org/pkg/cmd/go/internal/list/